# Retrofit object format customization

Tags: android, retrofit

I am sending a `@delete` request to the server with a body that contains an array of integers.

The object looks like this:

```
[1,2]
```

But i need it to have an id name like this:

```
["Id":{1,2}]
```

How do i achieve that?

I'm using retrofit2 and android studio

Comment: convert your data in jsonobject

Comment: Elaborate please

Comment: ["Id":{1,2}]  this is a jsonArray first you have to convert your date (1,2) into jsonObject after that convert jsonobj into jsonArray i will post answer with code wait

Answer (score 1):

Convert your value into JSONObject and than pass it into retrofit .try this one here's the code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject()
json.put("valA","1")
json.put("valB" , "2")

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray()
jsonArray.put(json)

JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject()
json.put("id",jsonArray)
```